# Can linux redirection command return an image file?

Tags: linux, redirect, command-line

Is that valid?

```
/home/testing# program > salida.jpg
```

Suppose that "program" is a C code that return and image file.

Comment: before doing it, I would like to know the opinion of some expert.. so.. no, do you know something about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course ! I use it frequently as

```
pnmtojpeg bla.pnm > bla.jpg
```